# Core dump : Extract all the global variables , data structures and sub-structures from a core dump

Tags: python, c, gdb, coredump, gdb-python

how to extract all the global variables , data structures and sub-structures (with address, type and values) from core dump,using gdb-python, generated after crashing of a C code.?

Comment: There is an open source project [Core Analyser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/core-analyzer/) that may have everything you need.

Comment: Why the python tags if this is C code?

Comment: @symcbean, because gdb extension supports python.

Comment: What is "gdb extension"? Gdb supports lots of languages.

Comment: @symcbean, means python script can be executed inside gdb promp,which make gdb very powerful

Comment: @PreetSangha, thanks but do you know how to do that under gdb?

Comment: @Baijnath: why must you use GDB if another open source tool can do it as well.

Comment: @Lie Ryan, Actually i want to write a script in python which will be executed under gdb to perform those operations.

Comment: is there any direct command to get all the global symbols name and value inside gdb?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to iterate over symbol tables from Python yet.  So, it can't be done.

However, adding support to expose this information to Python would be a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @Tromey , Thanks. So could you please guide me how to get all the global variables(excluding libraries symbols), data structures and sub-structures (with address, type and values) from core dump manually in gdb prompt .? so i will try to do this in python.

Comment: It can't be done programatically from the gdb CLI, either.  You have to extend the C code.